# Custom Callout View like MKAnnotationView's Callout

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom MKAnnotationView which I have customised according to the documentation of [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW30).

So far it's been really nice to follow it because it was very neat and clean code and I haven't used any third party for it. Here's the screenshot of it.

[image: Custom Callout]

Now I am stuck at the UI part of it, making callout look like native callout. I don't want to use any other third party in which I would have to redo my work or I have to abandoned guidelines of Apple.

So I guess I am looking for a simple solution which I can make in my Callout View's xib or similar.

Thanks,

Attiqe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have finally figured out a way. I was loading the callout view from a nib and I have made changing in it to mimic the native look. I have embedded my icons/uiimageview's into another uiview. Parent view will be transparent and child view(that contains all the icons now) will have another uiimageview(with callout arrow) at it's centre bottom.

This solved my problem.

Thanks,

Attiqe